# Disabling buttons temporarily while animation is going on?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am quite new to the *MATLAB GUI*. I made a simple GUI with some buttons in it. I attached an animation to each button. What I want to do is when an animation is going on all the buttons should be disabled till its over. I tried using a variable like a Boolean by using an if condition. Also I tried updating the handles before animation. But none of them worked.

```
if handles.animation == 0
      handles.animation =1;
     %%function is called
end
handles.animation = 0;
```

The above is the code I used. Am I making some logical error? or is there a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to disable a pushbutton/some uicontrol element, you want to use its "enable" property, setting it to either on or off as follows:

```
set(handles.animation,'Enable','off');
```

Then you could use a *while* statement to control the flow of your GUI. For instance:

```
 while strcmp(get(handles.animation,'enable'),'on') % if pushbutton of interest is enabled, then disable others:

      set(handles.animation,'enable','off');
set(handles.pushbuttonX,'enable','off');
% And so on...
     %%function is called
end
```

and so on.

An even more more elegant way is to use the [findobj](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) function to look for any element with their "enable" property to "on" and then set them to "off", as nicely demonstrated [here](http://www.matlabtips.com/cant-you-see-i-m-busy/)

Hope that helps! If it's not clear enough please ask!

Comment: the findobj was really helpful... Thanks